# Not finding the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1 [mysqli]

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got

> "*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1*"

message when I run this

```
private function saveBookingData(){
        global $mysqli;
        $sql = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO bsi_bookings 
                    (booking_id, booking_time, start_date, end_date, client_id, 
                     total_cost, payment_amount, payment_type, special_requests) 
                values(".$this->bookingId.", NOW(), 
                        '".$this->mysqlCheckInDate."', 
                        '".$this->mysqlCheckOutDate."', 
                        ".$this->clientId.", 
                        ".$this->grandTotalAmount.", 
                        ".$this->totalPaymentAmount.", 
                        '".$this->paymentGatewayCode."', 
                        '".$this->clientdata['message']."')");

        foreach($this->reservationdata as $revdata){
            foreach($revdata['availablerooms'] as $rooms){              
                $sql = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO bsi_reservation 
                              (bookings_id, room_id, room_type_id) 
                          values(".$this->bookingId.",  ".$rooms['roomid'].", 
                              ".$revdata['roomtypeid'].")");
            }   
        }
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
              exit();
        }

        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
             printf("%s\n", $mysqli->error);
             exit();
        }
    }
```

Other info
table 1

```
CREATE TABLE `bsi_bookings` (
        `booking_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `booking_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        `start_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
        `end_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
        `client_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
        `child_count` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `extra_guest_count` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `discount_coupon` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        `total_cost` decimal(10,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
        `payment_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
        `payment_type` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `payment_success` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `payment_txnid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        `paypal_email` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
        `special_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `special_requests` text,
        `is_block` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `is_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `block_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table 2

```
CREATE TABLE `bsi_reservation` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `bookings_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `room_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you please post your `data types` of the `database attributes`?

Comment: @Robin Gillitzer Okay

Comment: Did your read my answer? I think it is the solution.

Comment: @rick Your code is wide open to SQL injection (or would be, assuming that in reality the checkInDate or  checkOutDate values would probably originate from user input. Either way you should use parameters as standard practice, to avoid any doubt).

Comment: @rick there's a nice simple example for PDO (and other libraries) at [bobby-tables.com/php](https://bobby-tables.com/php), and [bobby-tables.com](https://bobby-tables.com) has a cartoon which gives a simple and funny explanation of how SQL injection can happen and what the risks are. Parameterising your queries is the only sure way to protect against it.

Comment: If you used prepared statements it is likely you would never run into this issue. By trying to make it unsafe you made your code too complicated. Keep it simple. Use prepared statements and [mysqli exceptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 2):

You may use PHP MySQLi Prepared Statements to Prevent SQL Injection

Expl :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO bsi_bookings (booking_id, booking_time, start_date, end_date, client_id, total_cost, payment_amount, payment_type, special_requests) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $this->bookingId, $var2, ....);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

[Read more](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: What should I put for datetime datatype in my table? Or decimal?

Comment: @rick use "s" for both. Actually you can use "s" for any type

Comment: Definitely not the OP's question.

Comment: @Your Common Sense I see, thank you

Comment: @RobinGillitzer definitely *the only* acceptable solution for the OP

Comment: @rick Let me expand more: dates are strings, integers are strings too, almost everything is a string. You can use `s` almost always.